# How strong is Freezer now?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Just watched Dragon Ball Super episode 95th (best episode ever some people says, last episode made record in ratings surpassing One piece ).
In it, (spoilers)

**EDIT: If someone can, please edit the spoilers area which isnt working**

> ! Freezer was able to handle with little damage a hakai energy ball mean to wipe out anyone not only from life but from existence and to control it.
>
> ! Later he threw it to Goku who wasnt able to control it and who got damage from it.
>
> ! Sidra says that if Freezer betrays him, he would take care of him, but a kaioshin commented it wouldnt be so easy for him to do it.
>
> ! Goku and Freezer sparring knocked themselves simultaneously , Goku was using super saiyan blue though he wasnt using super saiyan blue kaioken.
>
> ! Beerus comments Freezer is even with Goku

How strong is Freezer now? Is he stronger , equal or weaker than Goku? Is he in the level of Sidra?

> (since he was able to control Sidra's hakai energy?) . Beerus was able to remove Hakai's energy from Goku easier, so I take Beerus is still stronger than Freezer

Answer (score 2):

Based on Goku's and Freiza's double K.O. I think it can be concluded that SSJB Goku is as strong as Golden Freiza. Goku on the other hand,  has the ability to stack kaioken *20 on top of SSJB which would make him significantly stronger than Freiza and UI Goku manhandled toppo and dyspo like it was nothing. Toppo is stronger than SSJB Goku and Dyspo is almost at the level of SSJG Goku. So I think it's fair to assume Goku is stronger than Freiza.

Answer (score 1):

I would say Goku still has the upper hand if he would go all out, but Freezer would put a really close fight, well at least based on the info that we have been provided with. Regarding Sidra, no Freezer is not stronger then him. He was able to escape his attack, but that was just a part of his energy that he gave to his minion, in a straight battle he would take care of freeza.
In general, everyone is gaining huge power boosts in Super so the power balance is all over the place. Next week Vegeta could be the "strongest"

Comment: There is also more info on "how strong Goku is" in the last chapter of Dragon Ball Super Manga #25. Though I dont know if it's fair to compare anime with manga.

Comment: yeah they follow the same story but the execution is totally different this time.